# find/highlight common substrings between two buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs, substring

Can somebody tell me how to highlight common substrings between two buffers in Emacs?
I can write a script to do that but was wondering if there was a built-in macro in Emacs by which I can do this.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: When you say "common substrings", are you asking Emacs to figure out what's similar in the two buffers, or do you mean that you know the strings beforehand and you want Emacs to highlight matches in both buffers simultaneously?

Comment: I want Emacs to figure out what's similar in the two buffers. Thanks.

Comment: what do you *mean* by that?  If the lines in two buffers are just ordered differently, do you want the script to show all of that?  What if the *words* are ordered differently?  Letters?

Comment: Hi Trey, Assuming that the two buffers have unique sentences(unique sentences within each buffer), I was wondering if Emacs can highlight the common "substrings". For example, if the first buffer has: "hello world" and the second buffer has: "world war", it should highlight the string "world". I can sort the lines in the two buffers using M-x sort-lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to accept the converse—seeing highlighted *differences* rather than *similarities*—then the [*ediff* package](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/index.html) will handle this for you. Try the function [`ediff-buffers`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Major-Entry-Points.html#index-ediff_002dbuffers-9). You can run it interactively with

```
M-x ediff-buffers RET
```

and specify the first buffer to compare, then the second. The first one will wind up on the top and the second one on the bottom, assuming you use the default layout with the two buffers shown split vertically.